# ReplyKeyboardMarkup Selective Python can't write correctly

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I need to do so that when writing text in the *"Tesla Bot"* chat, only the person who wrote the buttons was displayed and not everyone in a row.

```
if message.text == "Tesla Bot":
        ye = random.choice(["I'm here, as always:(", "Did you call me?"])
        bot_answers = random.choice(["something important or bored?", "what you wanted?"])
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Bot who are you?")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Bot why are you here?")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Let's really talk next time")
 
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, selective=True).add(item1, item2, item3)
 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "{0} <b>{1.first_name}</b> {2}".format(ye, message.from_user,           bot_answers),
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
```